# Convert created process builder from workflow to invocable

Tags: process-builder, workflow

We have a process builder which is already activated and now we have to  change to **InvocableProcess** so instead creating everything from scratch, is it possible to convert process to invocable so that we can call it from another process?
We have tried via VS Code to retrieve code and then change this `<processType>InvocableProcess</processType>` but when we tried to deploy it gives following error
**formula_myRule_1 (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid: Function ISNEW may not be used in this type of formula**

[image]

Is it possible to convert process builder or not? If yes, please guide.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if such deployment should work, I wouldn't take the risk and would simple create it manually. Anyway, bottom line is that you cannot use functions IsNew/isChanged in invocable process criteria, therefore you will need to have changes in the current logic.

Comment: Yes, that is not working so how can I change the logic? Is there alternate available for such functions such as IsNew/IsChanged?

Comment: I guess for isNew you can set your process builder to work only when record created and then you won't need to check isNew. If you have additional actions in the process builder that run also on update you can use 2 process builders - 1 for creation that will do the invocable and other on create/update and do the rest